# Fail safe SSH tunnel Ubuntu (always up)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, mysql-replication, tunnel

I need your advise for a very important technical issue on our project. We need to have a SSH tunnel always up between our two servers. We have a MySQL database replication process going between those two servers.

We want two things:

- When the connection is lost it automatically reconnect without our
  external help
- When the computer restart the connection go
  automatically online

We are running under Ubuntu.

For the moment I have to manually check if the tunnel is still active. We use SSH Tunnel Manager to start the tunnel. Previously, we were using this command : `ssh root@MY_SERVER.com -L 8806:localhost:3406`.

Do you know a script or a software that may help us on that case? On another Windows machine we use Bitvise that can satisfy those criteria. Normally, I found Linux easier to adapt for those kind of things, but I kind of out of options this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [autossh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) utility may do what you want

> autossh is a program to start a copy of ssh and monitor it, restarting it as necessary should it die or stop passing traffic.

You should really do the job correctly and create a VPN between the two systems using openvpn (or similar).

Comment: I added this command in our crontab to solve the problem: `@reboot autossh root@MY_SERVER.com -L 8806:localhost:3406`. Thanks!